# Trouble Including php-encryption In Project

Tags: php, encryption

I'm attempting to use the defuse/php-encryption project found here: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

I've followed their installation steps to include the code into my project, but cannot get it to actually work. I'm trying to make an extremely basic "test" page (code below) and I've spent hours messing with this. I'm guessing it's something basic I'm missing, but I've really only used PHP functionally in the past (as opposed to an OOP fashion), so I'm stumped as to why this isn't working. In insight you could provide would be very appreciated and thanks.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "util/defuse-crypto.phar";
use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;

$passphrase = $_GET['p'];
$string = $_GET['s'];

$encrypted = Crypto::encryptWithPassword($string, $passphrase);
$decrypted = Crypto::decryptWithPassword($encrypted, $passphrase);

echo $encrypted;
echo "<br/>";
echo $decrypted;

?>
```

Attempting to hit this: `encdecTest.php?p=test&s=12345678`

just yields:

> Fatal error: Class 'Defuse\Crypto\Crypto' not found in encdecTest.php
>   on line 11

Note, I just started this today, so I'm on their latest release v2.0.1.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. What version of PHP are you using? Is phar support enabled? (you can check with `phpinfo()`)

Comment: This seems to be it! phpinfo shows "--enable-phar=shared" which I'm unsure what that really means, but Googling it yields me a number of specific problems with using phar on Dreamhost and that's where my server is hosted, so that's got to be my issue. Thanks for your help and for hinting me in the correct direct. We have a Dedicated Server, so I'll see what I can do to enable phar correctly.

Comment: Also, you'll want to put your `use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;` above the `ini_set`